# Will riding a rock dog allow me to walk in lava pits?

Tags: spelunky-2

The Rock Dog is an enemy and mount found in the Volcana area. I've noticed that riding it seems to grant at least some level of immunity to fire damage.

Does this immunity extend to lava? Lava normally kills you on one hit, so it's not exactly something I can safely test myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I decided to just yolo it and test this out myself, and I was filled with **instant regret**

Rock Dogs will ***not*** make you immune to lava.

You will initially hop off the rock dog when making contact with lava, so there is a chance you can save yourself, but I definitely wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: My run was going so well too. I regret my willingness to sacrifice myself to provide this information to the internet at large.